PowerBI Azure-Devops: query not showing links (as shown in Msft sample query)
When I try to use the Microsoft learning example to retrieve Devops workitmes and related items, only the parent shows up. No attributes concerning Linked workitems are shown.
Used code is the exact example from Microsoft learning:
let
   Source = OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?"
        &"$filter=WorkItemType eq 'Feature' "
            &"and State ne 'Closed' and State ne 'Removed' "
            &"and startswith(Area/AreaPath,'{areapath}') " 
        &"&$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State,AreaSK "
        &"&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName),Iteration($select=IterationPath),Area($select=AreaPath), "
                &"Links( "
                    &"$filter=LinkTypeName eq 'Child' "
                        &"and TargetWorkItem/WorkItemType eq 'User Story'; "
                    &"$select=LinkTypeName; "
                    &"$expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemType,WorkItemId,Title,State) "
                &") "
    ,null, [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4]) 
in
    Source

I have a linked Feature as child from one Epic, however the result is only one line showing the Epic:


After we use Power BI query to get the Data from Azure DevOps, it only displays the source metadata in the original form.
We need to then transform select column data prior to creating a report. Here is a sample for your reference to expand the Links columns with the children features.

See Power BI data transformations - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn for more details and some other basic tasks to perform.

Thank you so much. I appreciate it. This is so helpfull. (Unfortunately I can't vote it up due to my 'beginner-state')

Glad to help and thank you as well for the sharing. Wish you a productive week ahead.
